# "The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found" checking subfolders from shared mailbox

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I created a macro that gathers all the timings from a specific subfolder on a specific date from a shared mailbox and personal sent folder.
When checking the timings from the personal sent folder there is no issue, but when checking from the subfolders from the shared mailbox sometimes I get the error

> "Run-time error' -2147221233 (8004010f)':
> The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found."

Also, after some testing noticed that force-closing Outlook helps minimizing the issue since it forces to check directly from Outlook server.
This is a corporate mailbox shared by the team in different locations, and it is necessary to use VPN to access the mailbox.

This is a portion of the code where the error occurs:

```
Option Explicit
Public ufEventsDisabled As Boolean
Dim cvCheckBoxs As Collection
Dim CV1 As Worksheet
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim pass, path As String
Dim count As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim cnt, counter, i, index, ILS, HO, HOOLD, MONI As Integer
Dim first, plus, found As Boolean
Dim user, filter, time As String
Dim FilteredM As Object

Outlook.Application.Quit
Set WB = Workbooks("Tool.xlsm")
Set CV1 = Sheet1
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
path = WB.path
count = GetCount2
plus = False
found = False
counter = 1

CV1.Unprotect

user = Mid(OutlookNamespace.Session.DefaultStore, 1, InStr(OutlookNamespace.Session.DefaultStore, "@") - 1)

Do While (CV1.Range("F" & count).Value) <> ""
    
    time = CV1.Range("C" & count).Value
    counter = 1
    
    If CV1.Range("A" & count).Value = "Day" Then
        filter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & CDate(CV1.Range("B400").Value) & " 05:30' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" & CDate(Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")) & "'"
    Else
        filter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & CDate(CV1.Range("B401").Value) & " 17:30' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" & CDate(Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")) & "'"
    End If
        
    Select Case CV1.Range("V" & count).Value            
        Case "2. Folder"
            Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.Folders("CorpoEmail")
            Set Folder = Folder.Folders("Inbox")
            Set Folder = Folder.Folders("2. Folder")  'error occurs here
            Set FilteredM = Folder.Items.Restrict(filter)
        
            Do While index <= FilteredM.count
                Set Mail = FilteredM(index)
                If InStr(Mail.Subject, CV1.Range("F" & count).Value) And Mail.Sender <> "CorpoEmail" Then
                    CV1.Range("C" & count).Value = Format(Mail.ReceivedTime, "hh:mm")
                    CV1.Range("B" & count).Value = Format(Mail.ReceivedTime, "\ dd\/mm\/yyyy\")
                    found = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
                index = index + 1
            Loop
            Set Folder = Nothing
            Set FilteredM = Nothing
            index = 1
        
            If Not found Then
                Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.Folders("CorpoEmail")
                Set Folder = Folder.Folders("Inbox")
                Set Folder = Folder.Folders("4. Folder")   'error occurs here
                Set FilteredM = Folder.Items.Restrict(filter)
                
                Do While index <= FilteredM.count
                    Set Mail = FilteredM(index)
                    If InStr(Mail.Subject, CV1.Range("F" & count).Value) And Mail.Sender <> "CorpoEmail" Then
                        CV1.Range("C" & count).Value = Format(Mail.ReceivedTime, "hh:mm")
                        CV1.Range("B" & count).Value = Format(Mail.ReceivedTime, "\ dd\/mm\/yyyy\")
                        found = True
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    index = index + 1
                Loop
            Set Folder = Nothing
            Set FilteredM = Nothing
            index = 1
            End If
            
            If Not found Then
                Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.Folders("CorpoEmail")
                Set Folder = Folder.Folders("Inbox")
                Set Folder = Folder.Folders("5. Folder")  'error occurs here
                Set FilteredM = Folder.Items.Restrict(filter)
                
                Do While index <= FilteredM.count
                    Set Mail = FilteredM(index)
                    If InStr(Mail.Subject, CV1.Range("F" & count).Value) And Mail.Sender <> "CorpoEmail@corpo.com" Then
                        CV1.Range("C" & count).Value = Format(Mail.ReceivedTime, "hh:mm")
                        CV1.Range("B" & count).Value = Format(Mail.ReceivedTime, "\ dd\/mm\/yyyy\")
                        found = True
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    index = index + 1
                Loop
                Set Folder = Nothing
                Set FilteredM = Nothing
                index = 1
            End If
            
        Case "1. Folder"
            Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.Folders("CorpoEmail")
            Set Folder = Folder.Folders("Inbox")
            index = 1
            Folder = Folder.Folders("1. Folder")   'error occurs here
            
            counter = 0
            
            Set FilteredM = Folder.Items.Restrict(filter)
            index = 1
                
                Do While index <= FilteredM.count
                    Set Mail = FilteredM(index)
                    If InStr(Mail.Subject, CV1.Range("F" & count).Value) And Mail.Sender <> "CorpoEmail@corpo.com" Then
                        CV1.Range("C" & count).Value = Format(Mail.ReceivedTime, "hh:mm")
                        CV1.Range("B" & count).Value = Format(Mail.ReceivedTime, "\ dd\/mm\/yyyy\")
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    index = index + 1
                Loop
            Set Folder = Nothing
            Set FilteredM = Nothing
            index = 1
    End Select
```

The macro has no issues finding the CorpoEmail shared mailbox, and the Inbox of it but fails to recognize the subfolder of the Inbox.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have noticed the following line of code which doesn't make any sense:

```
Outlook.Application.Quit
```

Then I'd recommend using the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder) method for accessing public folders. It returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. For example, the following VBA macro shows how to use this method:

```
Sub ResolveName()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 

 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")  
 myRecipient.Resolve  
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
 Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 End If  
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = _  
 myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _  
 (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)  
 CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

Comment: The reason for that line is to force the macro to contact Outlook Server instead of using cached mode of Outlook, this has proven to improve the rate of success in not getting the error.

I can try that once again to get the default inbox folder and then set the subfolder, but that is not the issue. To that point the macro works fine, the issue occurs when trying to set the subfolder of the inbox, which fails to recognize (it assumes that there is no folders inside Inbox).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in the cached mode Outlook might not even sync the subfolders, only the default folders.

You should see all folders if the whole mailbox is open in the profile - can you see the mailbox in the folders pane? If not, add it from the Advanced tab of the Exchange account options dialog.

Comment: Yeah, that is not an issue since all folders are there because it is necessary for work.

Indeed we work with cached mode on Outlook, I think that could be the reason we are getting this error. Because of VPN might be a delay causing the folders to not be recognized.